# ggplot, Label small east coast states on US choropleth with floating colored markers

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to create a US choropleth and would like to add labels for the small east coast states, like in this example:

[image: example map, showing the value for the small east coast states as labelled dots in the atlantic]

The code I've been using for my map is

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data = usfix, map = usfix, 
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id), 
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#ffffff", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data = state.avg, map=usfix, 
                    aes(fill = score, map_id=id), 
                    color="#ffffff", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position = c(.15,.7))
gg <- gg + coord_fixed()
gg
```

I've attempted to add the labels as a new point layer

```
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=2500000,y=(-1:4)*(-100000), color = percentile), 
                      data=state.avg[state.avg$STATE_CODE %in% 
                      c("MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "DE", "MD"),])
gg <- gg + geom_text(data = state.avg[state.avg$STATE_CODE %in% 
                     c("MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "DE", "MD"),], 
                     aes(label = STATE_CODE, x=2600000,y=(-1:4)*(-100000)),
                     hjust=0, size = 4)
```

but this produces a second legend, and also puts the colors of the state label dots on a slightly different scale from the color of the states themselves (which would be even worse if `percentile` for these six states didn't span a good chunk of the range of `percentile` across the country - and I have no guarantee that it will for every map I want to make). [image]

Is there a less ad hoc way of making labels like this, that wouldn't spawn a second legend and use it's own color range? Or, if not, is there a way to remove the second legend and bind the label colors to the colors of the states on the map?

EDIT: I've figured out how to remove the second legend (`gg <- gg + guides(color=FALSE)` does the trick), but still have the problem that the color scale of the map and the color scale of the points are different.

Comment: You could use `ggplot_build` to get the color assignments then use them in your `geom_point` call. Also, you can use `rgeos::gCentroid` to get the state centroids for those smaller states to use as an x/y pair if you do want to draw a line

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! I'll leave a more detailed description of what I do as an answer on this question for posterity - that's the correct etiquette in the case of something like this, right?

Comment: aye. you'll be doing the hard work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following hrbrmster's excellent suggestion, I solved the problem using `ggplot_build()` as follows:

Making use of `str {utils}` to navigate my way through the `ggplot_build(gg)` object, I find that the colors for each state are in `ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$fill`, and the state labels are in `ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$map_id`. Thus, I can get the color for Utah using

```
ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$fill[which(ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$map_id == 'utah')]
```

Thus, I can color the points for the east coast states with

```
state.getcolor <- function(x) {
  ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$fill[which(ggplot_build(gg)$data[[2]]$map_id == x)]
}
eastcoast.colors <- sapply(c("massachusetts", "rhode island", "connecticut", "new jersey", 
                           "delaware", "maryland", "district of columbia"), state.getcolor)
```

And pass it to the `geom_point` layer

```
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=2500000, y=(-1:5)*(-100000)), color = eastcoast.colors, 
                      data = state.avg[state.avg$STATE_CODE %in% 
                      c("MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "DE", "MD", "DC"),])
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label = c("MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "DE", "MD", "DC"), 
                     x=2600000, y=(-1:5)*(-100000)), hjust=0, size=3, 
                     data = state.avg[state.avg$STATE_CODE %in% 
                     c("MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "DE", "MD", "DC"),])
```

I'm still not entirely sure why it fails with error "Error in data.frame(x = 2500000, y = c(1e+06, 0, -1e+06, -2e+06, -3e+06,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 7, 51" when I try to remove the data specification in `geom_point` and `geom_text`. I assume the error means that in the absence of specified data, it tries to use the data for the map plot, but I'm not asking it to do anything with data - just to plot points. So there's probably still a gap in my understanding of ggplot.